# New to Javascript: Popup Menu

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a website and I'm stuck now that I'm in JS territory. I am OK with HTML and CSS, but I feel like a total moron when it comes to JS.

Here's what I have (and I'm sure it's dead wrong) so far...

```js
var clicked = getElementById('loginIcon').clicked;
function showHideLogin() {
    if (clicked) {
        getElementById('loginField').visibility = "visible";
    }
    else {
        getElementsById('loginField').visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Please, be kind... I'm just starting to learn JS and I'm ripping my hair out and feeling like a complete idiot...

I'm trying to make a login  that only shows when an icon (png) is clicked. Otherwise, it's hidden.

EDIT: Thanks for the replies so far. This is how much of a noob I am: Atom says " Node is not recognized as an internal or external command" which, by Googling, I've found out means I don't have Node JS (which I have to research more to understand).

Thanks guys. I'll let you know if it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try

getElementById('loginField').style.visibility = "visible";

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the visibility correctly. It should be:

`getElementById('loginField').style.visibility = "visible";`

Also, I'm not sure when `showHideLogin` is expected to be called, but the norm for setting an *event handler* is to register a function. Something like:

```js
getElementById('loginIcon').onclick = function() {
    // perhaps some conditions or other logic
   getElementById('loginField').visibility = "visible";
};
```